# View.OnClickListener causing crash of tutorial app

Tags: java, android, onclick, crash, onclicklistener

First, I'm new to android SDK but I have a decent amount of experience in java. I'm attempting a tutorial on the SDK to get into it. I completed writing everything required but when I go to run it, the app crashes and I get this fatal error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
on a null object reference
```

Ok, sure. Clearly, there is an issue with View.OnClickListener. Spelling, check. Capitalization, check. Parenthesis, check. Brackets, check. Semicolons, check. Next I checked the documentation for View.OnClickListener. I see its only method is onClick(View v). Ok well everything is fine there. The IDE isn't giving me any other errors. So at this point, I figure I need outside help. For referance, this is the button id:

```
android:id="@+id/button"
```

This is MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                goToSecondActivity();
            }
        });
   }

    private void goToSecondActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
   }
}
```

And here is the logcat

```
 08-20 16:00:01.171 2565-2565/com.example.joe.helloworld E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.example.joe.helloworld, PID: 2565
                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.joe.helloworld/com.example.joe.helloworld.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                          at com.example.joe.helloworld.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 2):

You've forgotten to call `setContentView()` with the layout id that contains the `Button`.

Since there is no content layout, calls to `findViewById()` return `null`.

Comment: Yeap.. you are right.. I focused on the code written, and everything seems good.. didn't think of that missing line (y)

Comment: Yep this was it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set the layout for the user to view :
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Also Instead of using :

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            goToSecondActivity();
        }
    });
```

}

Just use this :

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            goToSecondActivity();
        }
    });
```

}

That means inside setOnClickListener use new Button.OnClickListener instead of View.OnClickListener

Comment: What is the advantage of that? I use:
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
}}

Answer (score 0):

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Right after super.onCreate(...)